# html.label not displaying the label

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am quite a newbie. As I am developing a sample application,I came across an issue.

```
 public class Dropdown
 {
     public IEnumerable<Drop1> drop1 { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Drop2> drop2 { get; set; }
 }


public class Drop1
{   
    public int Drop1Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class Drop2
{
    public int Drop2Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my model looks.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.drop1.First().Drop1Id)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.drop1.First().Drop1Id)
```

...
`textboxfor` gives the returned model value, `labelfor` is just displaying as **"dropid"**
.
Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DataAnnotations.
For example:

```
public class Drop1
{   
    [Display(Name="hello")]
    public int Drop1Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Now the labelfor will display "hello"